# Facebook payment subscription - client callback

Tags: facebook, payment, subscription, facebook-credits, asynccallback

I have added some credit test users to my app and try to make payment subscritpions. At the beginnings everything worked fine, but lately I'm getting some issues related to this. Further speaking, I'm getting the message: **Sorry, there was a problem and we can’t complete your request. Please try again later.** with consecuent client callback data setted to null. I suspect I didn't have made any significant change in FB.ui call for the subscription payment dialog. Could anybody share his/her thaughts about this?

I have seen into developers.facebook support pages and no much feedback is provided concerning to this.

Comment: There already was very similar bug, it was fixed, but now it does not work again for me... https://developers.connect.facebook.com/bugs/270125723108132

Comment: As far as I can remember, they had the same issue recently. By now there are no updates for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of things happen with Facebook notification services. I mean, the fb-service core some times just stop working and then come into service again as if nothing have happened. The delays in between could takes from some minutes to several weeks. Furthermore, rising an issue on Facebook developers site every time notifications stop working is not good at all.